# The keyboard shortcut setting doesn't respond to certain changes

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 19.04. I want to change the shortcut key for **Switch to next input source** to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I go to the **Keyboard** section in *Settings* and find the entry (under **Typing**). When I click on it a dialog appears, and says "*Enter new shortcut...*" with a keyboard picture under it. However, when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> it is dumbly not responding.

The current shortcut is in gray color as I thought it's disabled and I don't have the privilege to change it. Accidentally, I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and it responded that it is assigned to another command, but for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> it even doesn't guide me what the problem is. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't set <Alt>+<Shift> that way. Use _Tweaks_ instead.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 19.04 use the following method:

- Run `gnome-tweaks` command (*without* `sudo` of course)
- Select **Keyboard & Mouse**
- Click **Additional Layout Options**
- Expand **Switching to another layout**
- Select the checkbox at the left of **Alt+Shift**

After that, if you want to check the change:

- Go back to Settings and select **Region & Language**
- Click the gear icon ⚙ to the right of **Input Sources** to display the **Input Source Options** box
- Check that the new shortcut appears at **Next source**